# Matrix in C without arrays

Tags: c, matrix

Hello my coding teacher give us this exercise:

> "Write a C program that, considering two values *row* and *col* (both int) chosen by the user, prints a matrix composed by *row* rows and *col* columns in which the first element is 1 and every next element is the previous one incremented by one."

I know that a matrix can be composed with arrays but we haven't study them yet so I have to make that only using basic C functions. How can I do?

Comment: So far, have you tried something? It looks like your teacher wants to consolidate knowledge about a previous lesson.

Comment: Your teacher only wanted you to "print" a matrix, not to structure a matrix. You can print a matrix with only one variable like @doctorlove suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that, arrays can be used to store matrices like data in memory.

In your case, yout don't have to store anything. The problem is only about displaying matrix.

Please try to implement following steps in `C`.

> - Initialize counter to 1
> - For i = 1 to `row`
>
>   - For j = 1 to `col`
>
>     - Display `counter`
>     - Increment `counter`
>   - Put a line break

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on a bit of paper.

Choose rows, say 2, and columns say 3.
You need a current value, starting at 1.

Write this down

```
1
```

Now move a bit and write the next value

```
1  2
```

Same again

```
1  2  3
```

... keep an eye on how many numbers you have printed out... We're at the 3 columns now.
So, print a new line `'\n'` and continue

```
1  2  3
4
```

This might end up being a bit wonky if the numbers get big, but you need a `current_value` starting at 1, and a loop, over rows and columns.

You can walk over the numbers and print as you go, rather than storing them.

```
int current_value = 1;
for(int row=0; row < rows; ++row)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
    {
        printf("%i ", current_value++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for the matrix elements using malloc(). You'll need columns * rows * element size bytes.

malloc() will return you a pointer to the memory.

Use pointer arithmetic to access the elements.

Comment: OTOH, this may be more than being really asked/expected from you.

Comment: `malloc`ating before learning `array` :)